# Sorted Tuples without Filtering

Tags: filtering, combinatorics, sorting, tuples

Say I have a list $L$ where the elements can be sorted into some canonical order. I want to use `Tuples[L,m]` but I only want the output lists to be sorted and without repetition at any level. What I've currently got is

```
pretup = Tuples[L, m];
nextup = Table[Sort[pretup[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[L]^m}];
nextup = DeleteDuplicates[nextup];
finaltup = {};
Do[If[Length[DeleteDuplicates[nextup[[i]]]] == Length[nextup[[i]]], 
  AppendTo[finaltup, nextup[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[nextup]}]
finaltup
```

but this is very inefficient. It first constructs all the possible combinations, then sorts them, then filters out duplicate sublists, then filters out duplicates within the sublists. Is there a faster way to do this? If so, what is it?

Comment: Please assign values to `L` and `m`. Thanks.

Comment: The function you are looking for is: Subsets. E.g.: `Subsets[L, {m}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber can you please make this an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is: Subsets.

E.g. for a list with n=5 elements and tuples with m=3 elements (note, you should not use capitalized variable names as those are used by the system):

```
n = 5;
m = 3;
l = Range[n];
Subsets[l, {m}]
```

[image]